# "non-integer constant in ORDER BY" when using pg-promise with named parameters

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I am trying to write a simple query using the pgp-promise library.  My original implementation looks like:

```
var bar = function(orderBy){
  var qs = 'select * from mytable order by ${orderBy};';
  return db.many(qs,{orderBy:orderBy});
}
...
bar('id').then(...)
```

But this gives an error of `non-integer constant in ORDER BY`
I have also tried adding quotes aroung `${orderBy}` and adding double quotes to the orderBy paramater to no avail.  I have a working solution by doing `var qs = 'select * from mytable order by "' + orderBy + '";'` though it should be obvious why I don't want code like that in the project.

My question: Is there a way to get pg-promise to build a query with an order by clause that isn't vulnerable to sql injection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get pg-promise to build a query with an order by clause that isn't vulnerable to sql injection?

The value for `ORDER BY` clause is an SQL name, and it is to be formatted using [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names):

```js
const bar = function(orderBy) {
    const qs = 'select * from mytable order by ${orderBy:name}';
    return db.many(qs, {orderBy});
}
```

whereas `:raw` / `^` is injecting [raw text](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#raw-text), which is vulnerable to SQL injections when it comes from outside, and to be used only for strings that have been created and pre-formatted inside the server.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks